# Cs-cart - How to seperate functionaly From add to cart bundle into Add to cart , Wishlist and Notification

Tags: smarty, cs-cart

I am a new to cs-cart. Not familiar with it . I need to separate wishlist, add to cart and notification functionality. When I use default cs cart add to cart bundle then comming three Add to cart , Wishlist and Notification buttion But  I need to only one.

```
<div class="bk-product-list__control">
        {assign var="add_to_cart" value="add_to_cart_`$obj_id`"}
        {$smarty.capture.$add_to_cart nofilter}  
</div>
```

This code showing three button add to cart , wishlist and Notification

I want to seperate

Comment: Please help me As per my need I am not finding solution any where

Comment: Your question is to extensively to answer on it.

Comment: <div class="bk-product-list__control">
        {assign var="add_to_cart" value="add_to_cart_`$obj_id`"}
        {$smarty.capture.$add_to_cart nofilter}  </div>